# How does Nginx reverse proxy HLS?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-live-streaming

I have a question, is it possible for Nginx to proxy HLS video streaming?

Example HLS.

```
https://bcliveunivsecure-lh.akamaihd.net/i/un150_A1_1@575439/master.m3u8
```

Access link after reverse proxy.

```
http://my_server_ip/proxy/un_live.m3u8
```

Before asking this question, I tried to turn to search engines and found very little useful information. Can you all help answer this question? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  Unless you're doing some transcoding or latency hacks, serving HLS is no different than serving any other static files over HTTP.

Comment: Can you provide the nginx configuration file to make it work? Thank you!